# A layout element won't center... why?

Tags: xml, android-layout

Here you can see I've got the LL_BtnR layout inside the longer linearLayout3.
LL_BtnR's gravity is set to 'center', yet no matter what, it appears in the left corner.

Any ideas what to do to get the content of linearLayout3 centers?

[image]

Thanks!

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/linearLayout1" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:background="@layout/backrep" android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_gravity="center">
        <LinearLayout android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:id="@+id/linearLayout2" android:background="@drawable/spell_frame" android:layout_marginBottom="10px" android:layout_marginTop="5px" android:layout_gravity="center">
            <TextView android:text="TextView" android:textColor="#FFFFFF" android:id="@+id/textView1" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:paddingTop="7px" android:paddingLeft="15px" android:typeface="sans"></TextView>
        </LinearLayout>


        <LinearLayout android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:id="@+id/linearLayout3" android:layout_marginLeft="5px" android:layout_marginRight="5px" android:layout_gravity="center">

            <LinearLayout android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_marginLeft="5px" android:layout_marginBottom="5px" android:layout_marginRight="5px" android:layout_marginTop="5px" android:id="@+id/LL_BtnR" android:onClick="onButtonClick" android:layout_gravity="center">
                <ImageView android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/ImageView01" android:src="@drawable/button_left" android:layout_width="wrap_content"></ImageView>
                <FrameLayout android:id="@+id/frameLayout1" android:layout_height="match_parent" android:background="@layout/butrep" android:layout_width="40px" android:layout_gravity="center">
                    <ImageView android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:src="@drawable/bun_r" android:id="@+id/imageView2" android:layout_gravity="center"></ImageView>
                </FrameLayout>
                <ImageView android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/imageView1" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:src="@drawable/button_right"></ImageView>
            </LinearLayout>

        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the gravity for the enclosing LinearLayout to center.

Comment: Done... same, doesn't change anything.

Comment: can you post your xml for this layout file?

Comment: Honestly what are you trying to do? For now just add android:orientation="vertical" in LL3